# Check if host is connected to LAN

Tags: python-3.x, ping, lan, arp

I am writing a Python surveillance script for my home.
I have manually set a static LAN IP address to my phone by it's MAC address.

The Python script should check from time to time if my phone is still connected to the network. When I disconnect the script shall then continue and start the RTSP stream in my script.

**The question**
*What is the simplest and best way to check if my phone is connected to the network or not?*

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to ping your phone from time to time. Here's a bash example which I'm sure could be adapted to python one way or another:

```
ping -c2 192.168.1.200 >/dev/null && echo phone is connected || echo phone is offline
```

Just check the return code of the ping command.